# Realm changing values from edittext

Tags: android, kotlin, realm

I have the following problem:

For my current Android app project I'm using Realm as a database and im trying to update a string value every time my a certain textfield changes with the value thats been given to the textview. Problem is though, whenever the value of the object gets changed, the value of the textfield buggs out with previously set characters and changes back. The item that I change is also inside my viewholder. Any ideas?
Heres my code

The layout

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/entry_detail_form_8_til_text_field_container"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    app:hintEnabled="true"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/entry_detail_form_8_title"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/entry_detail_form_8_et_text_field"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

and the logic

```
holder.etTextArea?.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher{
        override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {

        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {

        }

        override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
            realm.executeTransaction {
                holder.fieldObject?.value = p0.toString()
            }
        }
    })
```

Edit: The following actions did not solve the problem:

- Extracting the change realm object logic into a callback outside the adapter
- Moving the logic into afterTextChanged

Comment: try `afterTextChanged` instead of `onTextChanged`

Comment: @LordRaydenMK same result

Comment: are you  setting the text to "holder.etTextArea"? any where .

Comment: @R7G no, weirdly enough, the bug only occurs when I add the "field.value = value" line to the logic, without it, nothing is being triggered twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by disabling autoUpdate in Adapter of my RecyclerView, seems like somehow the value of my edit text was connected with the field i was changing with the new text

Comment: Now if you delete an item in the Realm and scroll down, your app will likely crash.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce no, that did not happen, also my app doesnt revolve around deleting items, just changing their values

Comment: @sixeco How do you disable autoUpdate in Adapter?

Comment: @AdromilBalais it's a parameter, or a contructor value